# How to open open a side panel upon a button press using vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing my first app with Vue and need some advice with trying to open a panel upon pressing a button in the header.

I'm starting with a basic HTML template, trying to add interactivity after pressing a button that's contained in the header.

When pressing the button, I'm getting the following message in the console:

> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got
>   undefined
>
> (found in )

The code I'm using is as follows:

HTML:

```
<!-- Doctype HTML5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" />

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

  {{ $style := resources.Get "scss/main.scss" | toCSS | minify | fingerprint }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $style.Permalink }}">

  <script src="js/vue.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vue-proj-info.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
      <header>

      <div class="h-branding">
        <div id="h-nLogo">
          <img src="img/med-logo-rev.png"height="70" />
        </div>
        <div id="h-title">
          <h1>Executive Blueprint</h1>
          <p class="subheader"><span class="tr-tier">Tier 1</span> - <span class="tr-service">Executive</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="h-toggles">
        <div class="buttonGroup">
          <button type="" name="tier1">Tier 1</button>
          <button type="" name="tier2">Tier 2</button>
          <button type="" name="tier3">Tier 3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonGroup">
          <button type="" name="executive">Executive</button>
          <button type="" name="concierge">Concierge</button>
        </div>

          </div>

  <proj-slideout ref="proj-slideout" id="proj-slideout" :class="{ isOpen: isOpen }">></proj-slideout>


      <div id="h-infoButton">
        <div class="buttonGroup">
          <button type="button" name="projInfo" class="proj-slideout-opener"
             @click="open">Project Information</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      </header>
```

JS:

```
    Vue.component('proj-slideout', {
  template: '#proj-slideout',
  props: ['show'],
  data: () => ({
    isOpen: false,
    projContent: 'overview' /* overview, jtbd, tiers, files */
  }),
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    open() {
      this.isOpen = true;
      console.log('Open Panel');
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var app = new Vue({
    el: 'header'
  })
});
```

SCSS:

```
#proj-slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease(out-cubic);
  display: none;

  &.isOpen {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
```

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Any chance you could set this up in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `@click="open"` is refer to Vue parent component scope, so you should define `isOpen` and `open` in parent Vue component

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var app = new Vue({
    el: 'header',
    data: () => ({
      isOpen: false,
    }),
    methods: {
      close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
      },
      open() {
        this.isOpen = true;
        console.log('Open Panel');
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use `v-show`

On the template In your component tag add `v-if` or `v-show` like so :

```
<projContent v-show="isOpen" ... />
```

On the trigger button use directly the click event to set `isOpen` to false or true like this :

```
<button @click="isOpen = !isOpen" ... >Project Information</button>//or even better @click="isOpen ^= 1"
```

Now when you click the button it will set `isOpen` to its opposite value, if it's false it will become true and your `projContent` component will show up, if it's true, it will be set to false, hiding automatically your component, you don't even need to set a method to get the job done, it's directly set in the event.

Don't forget to remove `display:none` from your `scss`

If you need to add a transition animation here is the link  "[Vue transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)"